# Cant save file in specific location, VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a script that splits a large Excel database into 30 rows, creates a new workbook for it.
and checks if there is a folder based on cell value if not then it creates it.
after all of that I want to save my files in that same new folder he created/checked for.
but for some reason after creating a string named path and populating it with the location.
I am receiving an EXPECTED ARRAY error when stating that I want to save it in the path value location.

```
Public Sub Split_30()

    Dim inputFile As String, inputWb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long, row As Long, n As Long
    Dim newCSV As Workbook
    Dim FileN As String
    Dim path As String
    
    
    FileN = Range("O2").Value
    path = "C:\OrderCargo\" & Range("O2").Value
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    inputFile = "C:\OrderCargo\Original\ãåç øëù î÷åøé"           'CHANGE TO YOUR INPUT FILE, OR USE GETOPENFILENAME
    
    Set inputWb = Workbooks.Open(inputFile)
    
    With inputWb.Worksheets(1)
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        
        Set newCSV = Workbooks.Add
        
        n = 0
        For row = 1 To lastRow Step 30
            n = n + 1
            .Rows(row & ":" & row + 30 - 1).EntireRow.Copy newCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
            
            If Dir(path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            Shell ("cmd /c mkdir """ & path & """")
            End If
            **newCSV.SaveAs FileName:=path**(inputWb.FullName, ".xlsx", " " & Format(Date, "mmm") & " " & FileN & "(" & n & ").csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            
            
        Next
    End With
    
    newCSV.Close saveChanges:=False
    inputWb.Close saveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Can anyone please try and help me find the error..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a race condition. The shell execution "mkdir" might not be finished before trying to save. Try the VBA command `mkdir` instead.

Comment: just changed the if dir commnad to " if MKDir"
and now i get "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignemnt"

Comment: I meant to replace the `shell` command with `mkdir path`